# Bash: update variable that uses a updated variable

Tags: bash, shell, variables, scripting

I am trying to get a little Backupscript running and I'm kinda stuck with something maybe so easy, but I cannot get it to work.

I use echo "backup 1 started" / echo "backup 1 ended" after each part of the backup (each called with individual scripts.) That's been running fine, but I want to use more variables so its easier to edit afterwards.

Here is my testscript

```
#!/bin/bash
# Backupcountervariable
bc=1
# Startbackup
startecho="echo $(date +%F_%T) | dobackup.sh | Backup "$bc" started!"
# Endbackup
endecho="echo $(date +%F_%T) | dobackup.sh | Backup "$bc" ended!"

echo $bc
$startecho
$endecho
bc=$(($bc+1))
echo $bc
$startecho
$endecho
```

The variable bc gets updated in between, that I know for sure. I think my problem is that one `$startecho` and `$endecho` are initiated they don't update `$bc`.

Any hints how I update a variable inside a variable?

---

EDIT:

Sorry for misleading you guys on what iam doing here. Here you can see the full backup script. It only calls the individual backupscripts and puts the output to the logfile.
So iam just executing this script via cron, instead of 5 scripts.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Backupscripte ausfuehren 0.5
# Created: 2013/05/30 22:00
# Updated: 2013/06/05 02:31
# 0.5: Log verbessert, teamspeak hinzugefuegt, backupcounter
# 0.6: funktionen eingebaut, uebersichtlichkeit verbessert

### Variablendeklaration
# Log Variable definieren
logfile="/var/log/dobackup.log"
# Backupcountervariable
bc=1
# Backupcounterincrement
function bci() { bc=$((bc+1)) ; }
# Startbackup
function startecho() { echo "$(date +%F_%T) | dobackup.sh | Backup $bc gestartet!" >>$logfile ; }
# Endbackup
function endecho() { echo "$(date +%F_%T) | dobackup.sh | Backup $bc beendet!"  >>$logfile ; }


# Start des Backups Ausgeben
echo "----------------------------------------------------------------"  >>$logfile
echo "$(date +%F_%T) | dobackup.sh | FULL BACKUP GESTARTET!"  >>$logfile

#### /var/www Backup
# Start Backup ausgeben
startecho
# Backupscript ausfuehren
sh /root/varwwwbackup.sh >>$logfile
# Ende Backup ausgeben
endecho
# Increment Backupcounter
bci

#### /var/customers Backup
# Start Backup ausgeben
startecho
# Backupscript ausfuehren
sh /root/customersbackup.sh >>$logfile
# Ende Backup ausgeben
endecho
# Increment Backupcounter
bci

#### Mysqldump Backup
# Start Backup ausgeben
startecho
# Backupscript ausfuehren
sh /root/mysqlbackup.sh >>$logfile
# Ende Backup ausgeben
endecho
# Increment Backupcounter
bci

### TS3 Backup
# Start Backup ausgeben
startecho
# Backupscript ausfuehren
sh /root/tsbackup.sh >>$logfile
# Ende Backup ausgeben
endecho
# Increment Backupcounter
bci



# Cleanup Backup FTP, remove files older then 30 days
echo "$(date +%F_%T) | dobackup.sh | Cleanup fuer den Backup FTP Server begonnen..." >>$logfile
#sh /root/cleanbackup.sh >>$logfile
echo "$(date +%F_%T) | dobackup.sh | Cleanup fuer den Backup FTP Server abgeschlossen!" >>$logfile

# Ende des Backups Ausgeben
echo "$(date +%F_%T) | dobackup.sh | FULL BACKUP BEENDET!"  >>$logfile
```

So my log looks like this:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------
2013-06-05_04:00:01 | dobackup.sh | FULL BACKUP GESTARTET!
2013-06-05_04:00:01 | dobackup.sh | Backup 1 gestartet!
2013-06-05_04:00:01 | Backupscript fuer /var/www/ gestartet!
2013-06-05_04:00:01 | Verzeichnis gewechselt! Beginne damit das Verzeichnis einzupacken...
2013-06-05_04:00:01 | Verzeichnis eingepackt! Beginne damit das Verzeichnis auf den FTP Server zu kopieren...
2013-06-05_04:00:01 | Backup erfolgreich auf den FTP Server verschoben! Temporaere Dateien werden nun geloescht...
2013-06-05_04:00:01 | Temporaere Dateien geloescht!
2013-06-05_04:00:01 | Backupscript fuer /var/www/ abgeschlossen!
2013-06-05_04:00:01 | dobackup.sh | Backup 1 beendet!
2013-06-05_04:00:01 | dobackup.sh | Backup 2 gestartet!
2013-06-05_04:00:01 | Backupscript fuer /var/customers/ gestartet!
2013-06-05_04:00:01 | Verzeichnis gewechselt! Beginne damit das Verzeichnis einzupacken...
2013-06-05_04:01:16 | Verzeichnis eingepackt! Beginne damit das Verzeichnis auf den FTP Server zu kopieren...
2013-06-05_04:04:56 | Backup erfolgreich auf den FTP Server verschoben! Temporaere Dateien werden nun geloescht...
2013-06-05_04:04:56 | Temporaere Dateien geloescht!
2013-06-05_04:04:56 | Backupscript fuer /var/customers/ abgeschlossen!
2013-06-05_04:04:56 | dobackup.sh | Backup 2 beendet!
2013-06-05_04:04:56 | dobackup.sh | Backup 3 gestartet!
2013-06-05_04:04:56 | Backupscript fuer mysqldump gestartet!
2013-06-05_04:04:56 | Verzeichnis gewechselt! Beginne mit dem mysqldump...
2013-06-05_04:04:56 | Mysqldump ausgefuehrt! Beginne mit dem einpacken des mysqldumps...
2013-06-05_04:04:56 | SQL Backup eingepackt! Beginne damit das Backup auf den FTP Server zu kopieren...
2013-06-05_04:04:56 | Backup auf FTP Server veschoben! Temporaere Files werden entfernt...
2013-06-05_04:04:56 | Temporaere Files wurden entfernt!
2013-06-05_04:04:56 | Backupscript fuer mysqldump abgeschlossen!
2013-06-05_04:04:56 | dobackup.sh | Backup 3 beendet!
2013-06-05_04:04:56 | dobackup.sh | Backup 4 gestartet!
2013-06-05_04:04:56 | Backupscript fuer /home/ts3/ gestartet!
2013-06-05_04:04:56 | Verzeichnis gewechselt! Beginne damit das Verzeichnis einzupacken...
2013-06-05_04:08:47 | Verzeichnis eingepackt! Beginne damit das Verzeichnis auf den FTP Server zu kopieren...
2013-06-05_04:17:08 | Backup erfolgreich auf den FTP Server verschoben! Temporaere Dateien werden nun geloescht...
2013-06-05_04:17:08 | Temporaere Dateien geloescht!
2013-06-05_04:17:08 | Backupscript fuer /home/ts3/ abgeschlossen!
2013-06-05_04:17:08 | dobackup.sh | Backup 4 beendet!
2013-06-05_04:17:08 | dobackup.sh | Cleanup fuer den Backup FTP Server begonnen...
2013-06-05_04:17:08 | dobackup.sh | Cleanup fuer den Backup FTP Server abgeschlossen!
2013-06-05_04:17:08 | dobackup.sh | FULL BACKUP BEENDET!
```

as of now only the dobackup.sh does the "| dobackup.sh |" output...

Greetings
David

Comment: Don't put code in variables.  You're turning code into data and then turning data into code.  That violates a lot of software laws.

Comment: The value of `startecho` is given a value that includes the expanded version of `bc` at the time it is assigned...which is 1.  You have to defer the evaluation of the strings until you've set `bc` to your required value.  But your code is ... kinda weird. Avoid putting command sequences into strings; it makes life very difficult for yourself, especially if any argument contains spaces that have to be preserved.  You have to worry about `eval` etc.  Yuck!

Comment: What you misreading is, that this is SIMPLY the "text" iam outputting to the logfile. This is not the backup itself. Timestamp | dobackup.sh (which is the script which executes the individual backup scripts) | backup 1/2/3... started/ended!

Comment: i updated my question with some explanation. Maybe your picture is getting clearer now.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of a string, you should use a shell function:

```
function startecho() { date +%F_%T ; echo " dobackup.sh | Backup $bc started!" ; }
function endecho() { date +%F_%T ; echo " dobackup.sh | Backup $bc ended!" ; }

startecho
endecho
bc=$((bc+1))
startecho
endecho
```

Comment: Thanks, that works! Altough i had to edit it because you missunderstood my output ^^  (the date  dobackup.sh belongs to the statement/is what is written to the log)  code: function startecho() { echo "$(date +%F_%T) | dobackup.sh | Backup $bc started!" ; }

Answer (score 0):

This won't necessarily work:

```
startecho="echo $(date +%F_%T) | dobackup.sh | Backup "$bc" started!"
```

You need to put `$(..)` around the entire `echo` statement:

```
startecho="$(echo "$(date +%F_%T) | dobackup.sh | Backup "$bc" started!")"
```